# Setup Flash Project

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flashdevelop

I Have to work with Flash very first time .

Here is my scenario .

1 .I have several ActionScript file with one having initGUi Method(May be Acting like Main Method)
2 .I have a page which has with embedded flash like this

```
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000" id="swf" width="600" height="400">
    <param name="movie" value="exp1/exp1.swf" />
    <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" />
    <embed src="Myflash.swf" width="600" height="400" allowScriptAccess="always" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
</object>
```

So When Pages opens InitGUI is called.

I am using FlashDevelop and I am not able to configure my project properly and I am not clear what Project type should be

Comment: What is Google search for "FlashDevelop tutorials" saying about that? You should read up on the project types so you know what you want to make. AIR is usually for compiling desktop/mobile apps coded in AS3 (Flash), If you want for browser then compiling a SWF/Actionscript project is enough. Also it helps to have understanding of C-like syntax (similar to C++ / C# / Java)

Answer (score 0):

In order to setup a new project, you have to do this:

Open FlashDevelop

Click on Project > New Project

Below "ActionScript 3" you have lots of project types. As a test, you can choose AIR AS3 Projector

Put the name of your project and choose the fold you want to place your project, then click OK

On the right side, you have your Project tree. Open the tree in "src", double click on "Main.as"

This Main.as is your start point. Try write the following:

```
trace("Hello World"); // You have to put this inside your public function Main
```

Save it and press f5. You should see an output message on the flashdevelop debbuger

Comment: When you open FlashDevelop for the first time, you will see the AppMan window. In order to compile in AIR you have to download at least the AIR SDK + ASC 2.0 package. (To open the AppMan just go Tools > Install Software